# Having multiple test nodes in testng xml is best practice for automation using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have basic question on how testng invokes the TestNG class while running automation if we are using below format in testng.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1"  >


    <test verbose="2" name="test1" annotations="JDK" enabled="true" preserve-order="false">
        <parameter name="testcase" value="22524" /> 
        <parameter name="data" value="testdata1" />         
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sanity" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="testscripts.Class1" method="method1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test verbose="2" name="test2" annotations="JDK" enabled="true" preserve-order="false">
        <parameter name="testcase" value="2" /> 
        <parameter name="data" value="testdata1" /> 
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sanity" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="testscripts.Class1" method="method2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So while running above testng.xml file how many times TestRunner create instances of Class1? My understanding is 2 times. So will testng create as many instances of number of test cases we have? Instead is it better to just run whole class? will that initiate only one class for all tests in Class1 like below? will this improve performance?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="suite" verbose="1">


 <test name="Tests">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sanity"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="testscripts.Class1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve from two tests? You are trying to pass different parameters - is that correct?

Comment: yes, each test takes different parameters.

Comment: Then you can't have one test and then have multiple parameters.  If you want to have one test then you need to use a dataprovider to solve the larger purpose of having same test run with different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What is the recommended approach in general with respect to performance? Running single class with all tests give better performance over having multiple tests in xml by giving different parameters? My each test case is different and unique so they take different parameters. I'm trying use best approach to design my test cases. I have around 2000 TC to run.

Comment: do u have ui based tests which take long or non-ui tests?  Multiple tests in xml is just adding time to create an xml (harder to maintain, harder to create) and an unnecessary task as such.  If tests are independent then running in parallel would give performance - testng as such adds very little overhead in terms of perf.